# iText Tagged Pdf Template and Image Reuse

Tags: pdf, itext

When generating a tagged pdf that reuses a PdfTemplate you are presented with this exception:

> Template with tagged content could not be used more than once.

Is it not possible in a tagged pdf to produce reusable content or is this just a limitation in iText right now?

```
void Main()
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 72, 72, 72, 72);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        writer.SetTagged();
        doc.Open();

        var canvas = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfTemplate t = canvas.CreateTemplate(6, 6);
        var disc = Image.GetInstance(t);

        var ol = new iTextSharp.text.List(false);

        var li = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem("List Item 1");
        var symbol = new Chunk(disc, 0, 0);
        li.ListSymbol = symbol;
        ol.Add(li);

        li = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem("List Item 2");
        symbol = new Chunk(disc, 0, 0);
        li.ListSymbol = symbol;
        ol.Add(li);

        doc.Add(ol);

        doc.Close();
        ms.Flush();
        File.WriteAllBytes("d:\\list.pdf", ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```